# Need hour min and sec in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am calculating the time difference between 2 times, I want to print the hour min and sec. Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

My query

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 114), CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), VCTime, 114)), 0), 114) AS TImeDifference 
FROM
    Test
```

**Output:**

```
TimeDifference  
---------------
10:51:37    
20:51:37   
21:51:37   
22:21:37   
08:51:37   
00:51:37
```

**Expected Output**

```
TimeDifference  
---------------
10h:51m:37s    
20h:51m:37s   
21h:51m:37s   
22h:21m:37s   
08h:51m:37s   
00h:51m:37s
```

Comment: Just a side note: You could optimize your current query to `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, GETDATE(), VCTime), 0), 108) AS TImeDifference` if you use seconds instead of milliseconds and the according format specifier (108).

Comment: Please stop entertaining, you are getting what you want in different ways or at least in my way but still you are waiting for more answers. Even you are not responding to the answer which you are said to check and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use sub query and concatenation operator `+` for `2008` with `DATEPART` function as below:

```
SELECT (
    CAST(DATEPART(HOUR,(TImeDifference)) AS VARCHAR) + 'h:' +
    CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE,(TImeDifference)) AS VARCHAR) + 'm:' + 
    CAST(DATEPART(SECOND,(TImeDifference)) AS VARCHAR) + 's')
FROM(
SELECT 
    CONVERT(varchar(8), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, convert(varchar(8),getdate(),114), 
    convert(varchar(8),VCTime,114)), 0), 114) as TImeDifference 
    FROM test
) t
```

Yes I realized `concat` is introduced in `2012` so we can use `+` instead

Comment: concat function is not in 2008

Comment: Yes, thanks for the quick response on that, I got the chance to update the answer accordingly. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below way

```
    DECLARE @x int, 
        @dt1 smalldatetime = '2018-08-17 03:24:16', 
        @dt2 smalldatetime = getdate()

SET @x = datediff (s, @dt1, @dt2)


SELECT convert(varchar, @x / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, @x, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108)
```

this will return **1:05:57:00**

Comment: I am getting the difference in my query I just need to know how to show H and M in my output

Comment: @RedDevil  there is no direct  method without logically making in hh:mm:ss in datediff

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be converting to strings to get the difference.  I think this should be fine:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
               DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(GETDATE() as TIME), CAST(VCTime as TIME)),
               114
              ) as TImeDifference 
FROM Test;
```

Then you want to add "h", "m", and "s".  You can use the STUFF() function.  But let me do this using `APPLY` so the code doesn't look quite so messy:

```
SELECT ( STUFF(STUFF(TimeDifference_str, 6, 0, 'm'), 3, 0, 'h') + 's' ) as TimeDifference_hms
FROM test t CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),
                      DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(GETDATE() as TIME), CAST(VCTime as TIME)),
                      114
                     )
             )
     ) v(TimeDifference_str)
```

Comment: Argument data type time is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: @RedDevil . . . Of course.  That should be `DATEDIFF()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select cast(date_diff / 3600 as varchar(4)) + 'h:' +  
       cast((date_diff % 3600) / 60 as varchar(4)) + 'm:' +
       cast(date_diff % 60 as varchar(4)) + 's'
from (
    select datediff(second, getdate(), VCTime) date_diff from my_table
) a
```

Comment: 'seconds' is not a recognized datediff option.

Comment: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.